# How to access Cookies cross-device/cross-browser?

Tags: cookies, cross-browser, cross-platform

Lets say a user opens website with utm from a third-party ios app with webview - instagramm, facebook.

E.g. example.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=advertisement1

Javascript on example.com creates a cookie with those campaign details. How can you see those campaign details if a user visits a website from a different device or browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out cookies are saved locally, and cannot be accessed from another device, unless you save them to a database and assign to a user, when he makes an authorization.

So basically if you want to keep cookies cross-device/cross-browser for a user, you should sync them with your user data in database.